# Why does Safari (both macOS and iOS) randomly drop cookies and local storage?

Tags: javascript, cookies, safari, local-storage, mobile-safari

I have a website where I store an authentication token in a cookie with 5-year expiration. Despite that, both desktop and mobile Safari tends to drop this cookie from time to time (sometime it lasts for 2 months, sometime it gets removed in a week). This is very unpredictable to my users.

I also tried storing the same token in Local Storage instead of a Cookie, the result is exactly the same.

Both the cookie and the local storage item are set by JavaScript / AngularJS on the client side:

```js
window.localStorage.setItem('token', 'secret-token');
```

```js
angular.module('app', ['ngCookies'])
.controller('Ctrl', ['$cookies', function($cookies) {
  var expireDate = new Date();
  expireDate.setDate(expireDate.getDate() + 5*365);
  $cookies.put('token', 'secret-token', { 'expires': expireDate });
}]);
```

I haven't found any documentation describing this especially random behaviour.

Comment: never used Safari in my life, but a quick search revealed [this article](https://www.theregister.com/2020/03/26/apple_relax_were_not_totally/) - it's a couple years old, but perhaps relevant (I didn't read more than the first sentence to see it may relate to your "issue" - *we'll delete local data after seven days but there's a way to avoid that*

Comment: This is exactly what concerns me: they say seven days, but in my case it's completely random: sometimes 2 days, sometimes 2 months, literally.

Comment: this is why safari is the new internet explorer

Answer (score 1):

On macOS, there is a [problem](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/safari-keeps-logging-me-out-of-all-sites.2343060/?post=31385556) whereby having the Developer menu turned on will cause this behavior. I don't know of a solution other than turning the menu off.

Comment: Very interesting, I'm going to give it a try!

Comment: Wow - this has been bothering me for months. Kept getting logged out of every site randomly. This solution worked, thank you!